# UIAlertController presented from UIBarButtonItem, wrong position after rotation

Tags: ios8, uialertcontroller

I have some `UIToolBar` with some button. I present `UIAlertController` with `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet` presentation style from this button. It is presented correctly, but when I rotate device this action sheet has wrong positions.

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIAlertAction* destructive = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:destructiveTitle style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:someHandler];
[alertController addAction:destructive];

[alertController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPopover];
alertController.modalInPopover = YES;

alertController.popoverPresentationController.barButtonItem = barButton;

alertController.popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;

alertController.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;

[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

One more thing here, `popoverPresentationController:willRepositionPopoverToRect` from `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate`is not called when I rotate device.

What is going wrong here, any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you found solution to this issue? If yes, please post your answer or any references. That would be really helpful as we are getting same issue.

Comment: @B.S.  i checked (both in stimulator iOS 8.4 and device iOS 8.0.2) the above code by presenting from a barbuttonItem.  It works well in portrait, landscape left, landscape right

Comment: The delegate method doesn't seem to get called when the `barButtonItem` property is set. If, somehow, you can get the frame for the `barButtonItem`, try setting the `sourceView` property to `self.view` and the `sourceRect` to the bar button item frame.